# Active Batches piling up with spark streaming with Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have developed spark streaming(1.6.2) with Kafka in receiver model and running this job with batch size as 15 seconds.

The very first batch is getting a lot of events and processing records very slow. Suddenly job fails and it restarts again. Please see the below screenshot.

It is processing records slowly but not as expected to finish all these batches on time and don't want to see this queue piling up.

[image]

How can we control this input size to around 15 to 20k events? I tried enabling spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled but don't see any improvement.

I also implemented Level of Parallelism in Data Receiving as below but still, I didn't see any change in the input size.

```
val numStreams = 5
val kafkaStreams = (1 to numStreams).map { i => KafkaUtils.createStream(...) }
val unifiedStream = streamingContext.union(kafkaStreams)
unifiedStream.print()
```

I am using 6 executors and 20 cores.

Overview of my code:

I am reading logs from Kafka and processing them and storing in elasticsearch in every 15 seconds batch interval.

Could you please let me know how can I control input size and improve the performance of the job or how can we make sure that the batches are not pilling up.

Comment: *reading logs from kafka and processing them and storing in elasticsearch* - And you're using Spark instead of Kafka Connect (+ Kafka Streams) for that?

Comment: Yes I am using Spark

Comment: Not my point. Are you aware of the features offered by Kafka Connect? If so, do you really want to maintain/monitor Spark code?